# How to skip confirmation screen upon contact deletion

Tags: contacts, search-results, confirmation, delete

When I do a search and select to permanently delete a batch of contacts, I am taken to a confirmation screen that asks me to confirm the deletion. I would like to (at least temporarily) skip/disable that confirmation screen so that when I select the Permanently Delete option, Civi would start deleting the contacts right away. How can I do that?